# Cannot upload images to the cloud using Cloudinary(paperclip) gem - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, cloudinary

I got problem with `cloudinary` gem when uploading images, here is my image model:

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord

  default_scope { where.not(photo_file_name: [nil, ""]).where.not(photo_content_type: [nil, ""]) }
  belongs_to :article, optional: true

  after_save :delete_invalid_image

  has_attached_file :photo, :storage => :cloudinary, path: "/uploaded/:class/:attachment/:id/:style_:filename", styles: { thumb: "300x200#", large: "1024x768>"}
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  #attr_accessor :photo

  def original_photo_url
      photo.path(:large, timestamp: false)
  end

  paginates_per 30

  private

    def delete_invalid_image
      if !photo?
          self.destroy
      end
    end
end
```

here is create method in image controller:

```
def create
      if !params[:hint].nil?
        @image = Image.new(photo: params[:file])
        if @image.save
            render json: {
              image: {
            url: @image.original_photo_url,
                  id: @image.id
              }
            }, content_type: "text/html"
        else
            render json: {
              error: "Something is wrong"
            }, content_type: "text/html"
        end
      else
        image = Image.create!(image_params)
        if params[:ajax_upload].present?
            image = {
              id: image.id,
              title: image.title,
              caption: image.caption,
              description: image.description,
              width: image.width,
              height: image.height,
          url: image.photo.path(:thumb)
            }
            respond_to do |format|
              format.json { render json: {image: image}}
            end
        else
            redirect_to admin_images_path
        end
      end
  end
```

When I trying to create(upload) a new image, the log show:

```
SQL (7.6ms)  INSERT INTO `images` (`caption`, `description`, `title`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('', '', '14696760_1230106580395129_29071409_n', '2017-01-06 00:43:51', '2017-01-06 00:43:51')
SQL (7.2ms)  DELETE FROM `images` WHERE `images`.`id` = 22
```

you can notice the insert and delete commands were happened simultaneously. I guest the problem come from the `create` method, but I cannot point out exactly where is it. Pls show me where I was wrong.

Comment: check why `!photo?` is true in `delete_invalid_image`

Comment: I used `photo.instance.photo_content_type`  to check and it return `nil` result, I just confuse that before I add `cloudinary` gem, the images were uploaded properly...

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this issue. It seems to work successfully for me. Specifically, can you please share why you chose to implement the `delete_invalid_image` method rather than doing `validates_presence_of :photo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using Paperclip raw with Cloudinary. There is a gem to use Paperclip with Cloudinary. Try using that instead.

https://github.com/GoGoCarl/paperclip-cloudinary

That gem says you can't start `:path` with a forward slash.

> You should specify the Paperclip path pattern that you would like to use to store and access your saved attachments. The value should be URL-friendly, **should NOT begin with a forward slash**, and, aside from forward slashes, can only contain alphanumeric characters, dashes (-), periods (.) and underscores (_). The path can be specified in your default Paperclip options or via has_attached_file.

Also don't use `photo.path(:large, timestamp: false)`. Use `photo.url` instead.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#view-helpers

Also, you seem to be missing fields. Paperclip will create `*_file_name`, `*_file_size`, etc. fields. I think your migrations are wrong.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#usage